# ArcGIS API 4.11 JavaScript Feature Table Alternative

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I cannot find a simple/basic example online of adding a feature table to the bottom of a map in ArcGIS API 4.11 from a Feature layer (using JavaScript). So the functionality would allow you to click on a single symbol on the map and it would bring back that features columns.

Example image:

[image]

So a basic code starting point would be:

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/esri/themes/light/main.css"
/>

<style>

  #viewDiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }

</style>

<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/"></script>

<script>
  require([
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/WebMap"

  ], function(
    MapView,
    WebMap
  ) {

    const webmap = new WebMap({
      portalItem: {
        id: "83bd8ae0349646a4bd98c1a60e7f835b"
      }
    });

    const view = new MapView({
      map: webmap,
      container: "viewDiv",
      constraints: {
        minScale: 300000
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```

I believe this functionality has not been carried over to 4.11 yet. The only example on line that I can find is below. But extracting the relevant code from the example I'm finding quite difficult. It seems that the code examples on the ArcGIS website are either very basic, or far more complex and there is nothing in the middle.

[ArcGIS Highlight features by geometry](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/highlight-features-by-geometry/)

Can anyone provide an example or point in the direction of one which is basic/clear/informative?

Comment: You never actually told us -- what feature functionality would you like the table to support?

Comment: @GavinR I have edited the question as requested. Hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: Was there any guidance on this question? I think this is a helpful subject. If I’m wrong please let me know.

Comment: @GavinR would you be able to provide any guidance here?